# How to debug cloud_firestore/permission-denied in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting error trying to create a document in firebase for a signed-in user.
How to interpret the error and debug it?

Is it because my rules reject the doc? Or, my application does not have certificate?
Or authentication in `FirebaseAuth.instance` is not visible to `FirebaseFirestore.instance`? If it is rules, any way to debug log the request to see why rules reject the doc?

Command:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collection.name).add(json)
```

Error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:32:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _JsonCollectionReference.add (package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart:109:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because my rules reject the doc?

Yes.

Do a web search for that error message to see lots of other people experiencing the same thing.

> If it is rules, any way to debug log the request to see why rules reject the doc?

In production, no.  There is no record kept of rule results.

If you want to see more detail about what happened while evaluating security rules, you should use the [firestore rules emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) on your machine locally.